# Issue when trying to show id dynamically in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**AppTabs.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div
    :class="{
      'flex space-x-4': variant === 'horizontal',
    }"
  >
    <ul
      class="
        list-none
        bg-opacity-30
        p-1.5
        rounded-lg
        text-center
        overflow-auto
        whitespace-nowrap
      "
      :class="{
        'flex items-center mb-6': variant === 'vertical',
      }"
    >
      <li
        v-for="(tab, index) in tabList"
        :key="index"
        class="w-full px-4 py-1.5 rounded-lg tabs"
        :class="{
          'text-blue-600': index + 1 === activeTab,
          'text-black': index + 1 !== activeTab,
        }"
      >
        <label
          :for="`${_uid}${index}`"
          v-text="tab.tab"
          class="cursor-pointer block"
        />
        <input
          :id="`${_uid}${index}`"
          type="radio"
          :name="`${_uid}-tab`"
          :value="index + 1"
          v-model="activeTab"
          class="hidden"
        />
      </li>
    </ul>

    <template v-for="(tab, index) in tabList">
      <div
        :key="index"
        v-if="index + 1 === activeTab"
        class="flex-grow rounded-lg p-4 tab-content tabs-cont-ht"
      >
        <slot :name="index + 1" />
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

**App.vue**

```js
export const datalist = [
  {
    id: 1, tab: "Tab 1a", val: "1", content: "Content 1"
  },
  { id: 2, tab: "Tab 2", val: "2", content: "Content 2" },
  { id: 3, tab: "Tab 3", val: "3", content: "Content 3" },
  { id: 4, tab: "Tab 4", val: "4", content: "Content 4" },

];
```

Where in the above code i have like ** :for="`${_uid}${index}`"** **:id="`${_uid}${index}`"** **:name="`${_uid}-tab`"**  Where it generates an id for the input field.

Instead of generating an id for input fields to be able to use the labels for this input field. Can i use my own ID Because my API have field like DeptId ( i tried to integrate my api, Then i come to know that if in api i have field like id then only my api is working or else it is not working i have tested..)

So can u please tell me, What changes i need to make in order to remove the auto generation of an id for input fields. And keep my id instead So that it works please.

Because i dont want to generate id by itself. instead want to keep id which is comming from an api like(DeptId)... And getting many error when i tried removing the id generation and bind my data from an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First defining slot should have a name not id for non-default slot.
So in AppTabs.vue you will have to change it to:

```
<slot :name="`tabPanel-${index + 1}`" />
```

And to override these slots, you either use the v-slot="slot-name" or use the shorthand #. So you would need to change your code in App.vue

```
<template v-for="content in contentList" :v-slot="content.id">
```

Or v-slot:[dynamicSlotName] in case you are using vue3.

Now regarding your code. The slot name you create `tabPanel-${index + 1}` will never be equal to the id you use in your parent component this code evaluates to the string "1-{{index+1}}". the slot name you defined will be overridden when you use v-slot with the name of the slot.

For more info i would suggest you read the slots doc in the website:

Vue2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

vue3: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I made the said changes like above. But unable to see output 
Can you please have a look at my code :- https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-tabs-forked-6ky5d?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: But what is tabPanel here.. because in my array i dont have any field like so...

Comment: Here is the fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-tabs-forked-enhie?file=/src/components/AppTabs.vue

Explanation: In vue when you are using custom slot name using  
v-slot:[dynamicSlotName]

Plus you were not creating the slot name correctly in AppTabs.vue , I also fixed it.

Comment: Thanks small information please. what is the **:for="`${_uid}${index}`"** **:id="`${_uid}${index}`"** **:name="`${_uid}-tab`"** Every time i see, **_uid** in all of them in AppTabs.vue component. Is it relates to the data field or ???

Comment: Because When I am integrating with the API, i see only tab names are displaying but not the tab content. So i am thinking what must be the ** _uid**.

Comment: The vm _uid is reserved for internal use and it's important to keep it private (and not rely on it in user code). Here its used to generate an id for input fields to be able to use the labels for this input field. If you found that my answers solved your question or have been helpful, please  accept it or vote for it.

Comment: Instead of generating an id for input fields to be able to use the labels for this input field. Can i use my own **ID** Because my API have field like **DeptId** ( i tried to integrate my api, Then i come to know that if in api i have field like **id** then only my api is working or else it is not working i have tested..)

Comment: So can u please tell me, What changes i need to make in order to remove the auto  generation of  an id for input fields. And keep my id instead So that it works please.

Comment: Id of elements need to be unique. If the deptID is unique for all elements.  You can just add this id to the label and input field. 

<label :for="DeptId"/>

<input :id="DeptId"/>